# isset(); doesn't return false and inserts blank field into database

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, isset

I'm doing one of php tutorials in the web, and it was going all right till moment of inserting something to database with isset in forms conditionals. Well let's get to the code:

This is the insert into DB function (it's inside functions.php)

```
function addCat($cName, $cDesc){
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories (Title, Description) VALUES ('$cName','$cDesc')") or die (mysql_error());
}
```

Here's the form:

```
<form action="doAdd.php" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="CatName">Name</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="CatName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="CatDesc">Description</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="CatDesc" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

And here's form's action (in doAdd.php):

```
<?php
include('includes/functions.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['CatName'])){
        addCat($_POST['CatName'],$_POST['CatDesc']);
        header("Location: cats.php");
    } else {
        echo "please set a category name!";

    }
} else {
    header("Location: addCat.php");
}
?>
```

So the thing about the form is that it inserts blank fields, making blank records inside database. What do you think is the problem with isset?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `empty()` instead of `isset()` in this way:

```
if(! empty($_POST['CatName']))
```

`empty` test if the var is set and is not empty (that is is not `''` and obvioulsy other value like 0, false and so on).

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is it ok to use just simple if(var) conditional since it seem to work that way?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel In a non identical mode, '' it's the same that 0, FALSE and so on.

Answer (score 2):

`isset` just checks for the existence of a variable. If you want to test if it's not blank, you should use `!empty` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`isset()` checks if a variable has a value including (False , 0 , or Empty string), but not `NULL`. Returns TRUE if var exists; FALSE otherwise.

On the other hand the `empty()` function checks if the variable has an empty value empty string , 0, NULL ,or False. Returns FALSE if var has a non-empty and non-zero value.

Hope this helped !